# Breaking a location.hash into an array using Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to break a location.hash into an array using a RegEx. I can't for the life of me get the RegEx right.

the location.hash can be either "#/A/B/C/D" or "#/A/B/C/D/"

and must break down into "A", "B", "C", "D".

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't get much easier than:

```
var a = location.hash.split('/');
```

You still get `#` as first result, but you can easily remove or ignore it.

Comment: Well, that's an easier solution.

Comment: @Allan - that *is* a Regex `:)`, split is using a regex anyway, but it is dead simple in this case.

Comment: If you must, you can use `var a = location.hash.match(/[^#\/]+/g);`, but you don't really need it here.

Comment: Using 'split' does seem to be the most obvious, and easier to uderstand for anybody who has to maintain the code in future. Using var a = location.hash.split('/').shift(); will get rid of the '#', leaving and array with "A", "B", "C", "D" in it.

Answer (score 1):

I'd trim the leading/trailing guff then split on `/`:

```
location.hash.replace(/^#\/|\/$/g, '').split('/');
```

Answer (score 0):

match this regex-

```
(?<=/)[^/]*
```